# ClickOnce asking for a password everytime I try to run the app

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

I'm trying to setup a test app using ClickOnce as the deployment model.

It's all gone quite well so far. I signed the manifests with a test certificate, but now every time I try to run it in release or debug mode, it asks me for the password. Not only is this a pain, if it worked, but it's giving me the error message "Object already exists" and won't go any further.

I'd like to

```
a: not have to enter a password every time I try to run/debug the app
b: get past this error
```

Answer (score 0):

How old is the test certificate? The ones Visual Studio generates by default only last for 12 months. If you remove the pfx file from the project, does it run? I saw this behaviour when I was trying to run a colleague's old project and the test cert had expired.

Comment: the certificate is about 1 min old. I literally JUST created it.